# Error in connecting database with MySQL.connector in Python

Tags: python

**mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (111 Connection refused)
[Program finished]**

Iam getting this type Of error 
When I try to connect to database with mysql.connecto in python.how to make it error free

Comment: Post the code that you are using to connect

Comment: Is mysqld running? Have you connected to it successfully using other means? How? With what parameters?